# how to create documentation from markdown inside docs folder on github? javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, documentation

I have seen a lot of docs websites that have the same layout or same features.
so I am wondering if there is a library used by all these docs.

**how do they do this?**

`./docs` -> `files.md` -> `./docs/files.html`

> like you see there are a lot of files with `.md` (sometimes also `.mdx`)
>
> and they have the same functionalities (see below)
>
> so I am wondering if they use the same js library to generate it?

[image]

I tried to search in all the repo, what they are using to generate, but nothing says the name of a library?

is there an npm package or CDN link to that js library?

 that can get the .md files inside .docs, and based on the folder structure, create a list on the left with all topics, 2 buttons with next and previous, a button with edit this page on GitHub, etc...

> if isn't possible I will do it by scratch, but writing HTML for every doc is time-consuming.
> I prefer some markdown fast, build consistent docs, and automatically added to the first-page list on the left.
>
>  also the routing thing for getting previous and next elements I need to do it manually and this can be time-consuming.

is there something that does that for me, some web API that gets files .md if I need to do it from scratch?

 but still prefering **npm** package if there is.

---

**Example:**

> previous and next docs.

- react native

[image]

- deno

[image]

- lusift

[image]

> and they have a button with the text EDIT THIS ON GITHUB

---

- Mozilla docs MDN

[image]

> when scrolling, it will change the color of the currently viewed section

- sketch API

[image]

---

but I never find the name of the library.

---

other functionalities are...

- multi-page
  and much more...

(I tried to search on Github, but never find it)

it's there a good docs generator for a programming library that I create?

---

I also google it: https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+library+documentation

> but nothing. the libraries there are for API `GET/POST` swagger etc...
>
> but I am wanting a library for `functions` like if you write this function this happen, maybe also code snippet functionality to see what result give you that function.
>
> something similar to StackOverflow. text to HTML (but not need any server-side things comlicated... just keep it simple the files are inside .docs in GitHub, so just simple stuff.

maybe I am writing wrong the google keyterm

Comment: Facebook react-native-website uses [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/)

Comment: @evolutionxbox very very very helpful bro!

Comment: Next time, you can usually find the libraries used inside `package.json` files. I found it inside [website/package.json](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-website/blob/main/website/package.json)

Comment: @evolutionxbox one curiosity, how to know and get the name of the library by looking at open source code? I want to learn

Comment: @evolutionxbox package json yes thanks

Comment: @evolutionxbox write an answer if you want, I will upvote you and accept, it will be helpful to other people also (is the first question on this topic here on stack at least javascript)

Comment: I won't be writing an answer, because the question is technically off-topic (asking for an off-site resource)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to this, by using the @evolutionxbox comment.

**how to find?**

if you want to find what library is used in a GitHub repo,

 go to the **package.json**, there you can find the list of libraries that is used on the project

[image]

---

**the name?**

in this case, the library used is *DOCUSAURUS*

> link: https://docusaurus.io/

is very simple to config and solves the job!

and is used by

- Facebook,
- and other big companies like:

  - supabase
  - redux
  - etc...